# Javascript: How to get the value of a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a quick game where a player damages a enemy npc. I have a function below that does the calculation for the damage, but I can't get the console log to say i'm doing "X" amount of damage. What am I doing wrong? Instead, it just pulls up the function statement, but I want it to give me the functions value!

```
var damage = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    };
```

I'm calling my function in another code properly, but when I try to console log the damage in that other code, I get a error.

```
function attackButton() {
    darkwarrior.hp = darkwarrior.hp - damage();
    console.log(darkwarrior.hp);
    console.log(damage);
```

Comment: Probably because you aren't invoking it - `damage()`?

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `console.log(damage());` you will get the "X" amount of damage instead of the function statement.  So you could change `attackButton()` function to be:

```
function attackButton() {
    var damageDealt = damage();
    darkwarrior.hp = darkwarrior.hp - damageDealt;
    console.log(darkwarrior.hp);
    console.log(damageDealt);
```

Comment: That only makes it run the function twice and gives me a seperate number from the first time I ran it.

Comment: This worked. I guess I have to put the function inside my click button so it runs seperately. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, you want to log the result? If so, you can do that:

```
var damage = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    };

console.log(damage());
```

EDIT:

you forgot the (). + the value will not be the same if you don't put it in a variable:

```
function attackButton() {
    var amount = damage()
    darkwarrior.hp = darkwarrior.hp - amount;
    console.log(darkwarrior.hp);
    console.log(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use an expression to assign the value to a variable. Then log it. Then return it.

```js
var damage = function() {
    
   var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
   console.log(num);
   return num;
};

damage();
```

Comment: He wants to display the result of the function, not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```js
function NPC(startingLife, name) {
  this.hp = startingLife;
  this.name = name
}

NPC.prototype.takeDamage = function(amount) {
  this.hp = Math.max(this.hp - amount, 0);
  if (this.hp == 0) {
    console.log(this.name + " Dies");
  }
  return this.hp;
};

function damage() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
}

var darkwarrior = new NPC(4, 'Dark Warrior');

function attackButton() {
  var amount = damage();
  darkwarrior.takeDamage(amount);
  console.log("Dark Warrior took " + amount + " points of damage");
}

document.querySelector('#attack-button').addEventListener("click", attackButton);
```

```html
<button id="attack-button">ATTACK!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are just returning the value instead of printing it. You should instead replace return with console.log(

Comment: he want to do a function which calculate the amount. I guess the log is for debugging purpose.

Comment: console.log() merely displays the value. Or you can say just print it. It doesn't return.